# LaTeX equation does not render as in-line math with Jekyll and MathJax

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, equation, mathjax

I have some in-line math (i.e. `$ ... $`) which does not render on a GitHub page created with Jekyll and MathJax. I have already tried a thousand of different notations/formulations/combinations and can't find out why it fails.

The problem is that this Markdown/LaTeX code

```markdown
Again employing the linear combination theorem and applying the null hypothesis from \eqref{eq:ttest2-h0}, the distribution of $Z = ( ( \bar{y}_1 - \bar{y}_2 ) - \mu_{\Delta} ) / ( \sigma \sqrt{1/n_1+1/n_2} )$ becomes [standard normal](/D/snorm)
```

shows as

[image]

I understand that what I get is an interpretation of the plain text as Markdown code (e.g. italics), but I simply don't understand what is wrong with the equation (the many spaces in there were one of the first attempt to pull it apart a bit and solve the problem, but this didn't change anything).

I believe it has something to do with the `\bar{...}` (maybe also with the character sequence `}_`), since I have similar to problems on other entries of my page.

Example 2:

```markdown
where $\bar{y} _i$ is the average of all values $y_{ij}$ from category $i$ and $\bar{y}$ is the grand mean of all values $y_{ij}$ from all categories $i = 1, \ldots, k$.
```

shows as

[image]

Example 3:

```markdown
Here, $\bar{y} _{i j \bullet}$ is the mean for the $(i,j)$-th cell (out of $a \times b$ cells), computed from $n_{ij}$ values $y_{ijk}$, $\bar{y} _{i \bullet \bullet}$ and $\bar{y} _{\bullet j \bullet}$ are the level means for the two factors and and $\bar{y} _{\bullet \bullet \bullet}$ is the mean across all values $y_{ijk}$.
```

shows as

[image]

However, there are (i) instances in which `\bar{...}` is used without any problem and (ii) instances in which the same problem occurs without any use of `\bar{...}`.

Example 4:

```markdown
where $\bar{y} _{\bullet \bullet \bullet}$, $\bar{y} _{i \bullet \bullet}$, $\bar{y} _{\bullet j \bullet}$ and $\bar{y} _{i j \bullet}$ are the following [sample means](/D/mean-samp):
```

shows as

[image]

Example 5:

```markdown
Note that, because $0 \leq \mathrm{H}_\mathrm{bern}(p) \leq 1$, we have $0 \leq n \cdot \mathrm{H}_\mathrm{bern}(p) \leq n$, and because the [entropy is non-negative](/P/ent-nonneg), it must hold that $n \geq \mathrm{E}_\mathrm{lbc}(n,p) \geq 0$.
```

shows as

[image]

So what is the difference between these cases? Can anyone work out why those equations don't render?

---

For those interested, the referenced pages are these ones:

- [Proof: Two-sample t-test for independent observations](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/ug-ttest2)
- [Proof: F-statistic in terms of ordinary least squares estimates in one-way analysis of variance](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/anova1-fols)
- [Definition: Interaction sum of squares](https://statproofbook.github.io/D/iass)
- [Proof: Ordinary least squares for two-way analysis of variance](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/anova2-ols)
- [Proof: Entropy of the binomial distribution](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/bin-ent)

Further pages where the problem occurs:

- [Proof: Partition of sums of squares in two-way analysis of variance](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/anova2-pss)
- [Definition: Treatment sum of squares](https://statproofbook.github.io/D/trss)

Comment: How are you adding MathJax capabilities, and how do you deploy your Jekyll site?

Comment: Ah, I see, you fetch the script from a CDN via includes. Hmm. Interestingly, also the GitHub LaTeX has trouble with, for example, the last problem you show, and doesn't render the inline math.

Comment: FYI, it's not a general problem with the integration of MathJax into the site. I have thousands of functioning equations. If you still want to know, see my question from last week: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77333242/12468874

Comment: The problem is an interaction of Markdown syntax with LaTeX syntax, in particular the use of underscores to delimit italics in Markdown.  Note that your examples that fail to typeset have the LaTeX displayed partly in italics and with some underscores missing.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74144860/mathjax-render-issues-on-combination-of-bmatrix-from-jekyll-with-kramdown for more details.

Comment: @DavideCervone: I think I understand this part, but for me, this doesn't explain why it happens in particular to those equations. There are thousands of functioning equations with underscores in our project, so what is so special about those equations? I want to know the defining feature, so that I learn how I can avoid this.

Comment: The underscores need to be paired properly for them to be treated as italics.  Depending on the Markdown engine, that usually means that the first one must have a word break before it and the last one a break after it.  So in your example 2, the `_` in `\bar{y}_i` has a word break in front of it due to the `}` and not after it, while `y_{ij}`has a word break after it for the `{` but not before it.  So those two are matched as italic delimiters.  Then that makes the end `$` for the first math and the initial `$` for the second become math delimiters, causing the text between them to be typeset.